# Using other classes to modify panel within Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

The program i am trying to make involves one main form, which should be able to switch between 5 different menus. Programming all the functionality within the `Form.cs` file would make this an extremely long class, so what i want to do is call the Panel from another class to add control elements and load all the data from a MySQL database, depending on the menu chosen.

More specifically I have my `ParentInterface.cs`, where I want to show a ChoreUI within a dynamic Panel which will be modified in a new class called `ChoreUI.cs`.

I have tried making ChoreUI inherit from the ParentInterface, as well as making it the target. Though my lack of knowledge of Windows Forms is in the way.

**ParentInterface.cs**

```
namespace ChoreApplication.UI{
public partial class ParentInterface : Form
{
    private ChoreUI ChoreUI;
    private ParentInterface PUI;
    public ParentInterface()
    {
        ChoreUI = new ChoreUI(PUI);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ChoreNavButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ChoreUI = new ChoreUI(PUI);
        ChoreUI.DillerDaller();
    }
}
```

**ChoreUI.cs**

```
namespace ChoreApplication.UI
{
    class ChoreUI
    {
    public ParentInterface PUI;

    public ChoreUI(ParentInterface PUI)
        {
            this.PUI = PUI;
        }

    public void DillerDaller()
    {
        PUI.dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(10, 10), Name="textName", Text = "hello"});
    }
}
```

I want to be able to add new control elements to the Panel, from the `ChoreUI` class instead of in the `ParentInterface` class. But as of now I am not succeeding in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

What you have at the moment is not **that** bad, your child component has a reference to the parent and that's ok.

This, however, is the issue

```
public void DillerDaller()
{
    PUI.dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(new Label { Location = new Point(10, 10), Name="textName", Text = "hello"});
}
```

At the basic level, you violate the encapsulation principle, where the `dynamicPanel` is `protected` inside the form so that it's not accessible from outside. Inheriting the child component from the main form **is not** the right solution.

At somewhat higher level, you violate here the so called **Law of Demeter** where the inner implementation details of a component should not be that misused. Changing the `dynamicPanel` visibility to `public` will not help. Rather, the rule says you should wrap such implementation details with a stable interface

```
public partial class ParentInterface : Form
{
    ...

    public void AddDynamicPanelControl( Control control ) {
      this.dynamicPanel.Controls.Add( control );
    }
    public void RemoveDynamicPanelControl( Control control ) {
      this.dynamicPanel.Controls.Remove( control );
    }
}
```

and use the newly introduced interface

```
public void DillerDaller()
{
    var label = new Label { Location = new Point(10, 10), Name="textName", Text = "hello"};
    this.PUI.AddDynamicPanelControl( label );

    // if you store the reference to the label somewhere,
    // you'll be able to call `Remove....` to remove this control from 
    // the form
}
```

Comment: This is great thanks.
But it raises me a System.NullReferenceException, stating that PUI was null.

Comment: Pay attention to what you pass to the `ChoreUI` constructor as `PUI`.